# MarkLogic - Use PojoQueryBuilder to do a 'like' search

Tags: marklogic, nosql

Say I have a JSON saved in ML8 as :

```
{
  "com.marklogic.poc.java.api.pojos.ProviderJSON": {
    "providerId": "1111",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": "41",
    "gender": "M"
  }
}
```

I have tried doing searches using following methods to search whole json or any specific attribute:

- term
- word
- value

But if i want to find if 'Joh' is present in name property, I cannot use any of above. Is there any api method available which can be used..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to http://localhost:8001, selected "Documents" (the database associated OOTB with port 8000) and changed "three character searches" to "true".  Then the following code works for me:

test/ProviderJSON.java:

```
package test;

import com.marklogic.client.pojo.annotation.Id;

public class ProviderJSON {
    @Id
    public String providerId;
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String gender;

    public String toString() {
        return
          "providerId:" + providerId + "\n" +
          "name:"       + name + "\n" +
          "age:"        + age + "\n" +
          "gender:"     + gender + "\n";
    }
}
```

and Test.java:

```
import test.ProviderJSON;

import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory;
import static com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.PojoRepository;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.PojoPage;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.PojoQueryDefinition;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatabaseClient client = 
            DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost", 8000, "admin", "admin", DIGEST);

        PojoRepository<ProviderJSON, String> providers = 
            client.newPojoRepository(ProviderJSON.class, String.class);

        ProviderJSON provider1 = new ProviderJSON();
        provider1.providerId = "1111";
        provider1.name = "John Doe";
        provider1.age = "41";
        provider1.gender = "M";

        providers.write(provider1);

        PojoQueryDefinition query = client.newQueryManager()
            .newStringDefinition().withCriteria("Joh*");
        int start = 1;
        PojoPage<ProviderJSON> matches = providers.search(query, start);
        try {
            System.out.println("string matches.size() =[" + matches.size()  + "]");
            for ( ProviderJSON match : matches ) {
                System.out.println("string match.providerId =[" + match.providerId  + "]");
            }
        } finally { matches.close(); }

        query = providers.getQueryBuilder()
            .word("name", "Joh*");
        matches = providers.search(query, start);
        try {
            System.out.println("word matches.size() =[" + matches.size()  + "]");
            for ( ProviderJSON match : matches ) {
                System.out.println("word match.providerId =[" + match.providerId  + "]");
            }
        } finally { matches.close(); }

        query = providers.getQueryBuilder()
            .value("name", "Joh* *");
        matches = providers.search(query, start);
        try {
            System.out.println("value matches.size() =[" + matches.size()  + "]");
            for ( ProviderJSON match : matches ) {
                System.out.println("value match.providerId =[" + match.providerId  + "]");
            }
        } finally { matches.close(); }
    }
}
```

Notice the value query requires a second wildcard to match any other words in the value.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sam.. all three ways are working. Seeing 3 ways to do it just wanted to know for a large number of files which one will give best performance or all three are more or less same !

Comment: Unless your data set is massive or your traffic is unbelievable I believe the speed difference between the three would be statistically insignificant.  If you don't care what field you're matching, the first approach (word query) is probably the simplest.  The second (element word query) and third (element value query) require an additional query resolution step of filtering matches to within a specific element.  There are many great resources out there on tuning queries: http://www.google.com/#q=marklogic+query+tuning

Answer (score 2):

Goel, you can use a [word search](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe#id_58335) with wildcard. You'll need to turn on one of the [wildcarding settings](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard) for your database. Below is a simple [QBE](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_33275) example. I enabled "trailing wildcard searches" on my database.

```
    DatabaseClient client = 
        DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(
            "localhost", 
            8000, 
            "admin", 
            "admin", 
            Authentication.DIGEST);

    QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();

    StringHandle rawHandle = new StringHandle();
    String rawJSONQuery = 
            "{  \"$query\": { \"name\": { \"$word\": \"Joh*\" } }}";
    rawHandle.withFormat(Format.JSON).set(rawJSONQuery);

    RawQueryByExampleDefinition querydef =
            queryMgr.newRawQueryByExampleDefinition(rawHandle);

    SearchHandle resultsHandle = 
            queryMgr.search(querydef, new SearchHandle());

    client.release();
```

Comment: Will try this Dave.. Before that just wanted to ask is there any way with the  PojoQueryBuilder, so that i get the java object.

Comment: Looks like Sam has your question covered.